# How to Select rows based on values in already selected rows

Tags: php, mysql

This is my mysql database. I have id, username, connect:

```
 id   | username | connect
 -----+----------+----------
  1   | a        |  
  2   | b        | 1 
  3   | c        | 1
  4   | d        | 2
  5   | e        | 3
  6   | f        | 2
  7   | g        | 3
  8   | h        | 4
  9   | i        | 5
 10   | j        | 6
```

I am showing like this: level 1 user a is connected with 2 users, so it should get a connect count of 2:

```
Level   |  Connect Count      
--------+----------------
  1     |     2
```

But now I want  to show 10 level results. I am showing level 1 result by selecting the level 1 id in the connect row.

```
for level 2 I want to search level 1 searched id 
for level 3 I want to search level 2 searched id
for level 4 I want to search level 3 searched id 
for level 5 I want to search level 4 searched id
for level 6 I want to search level 5 searched id 
for level 7 I want to search level 6 searched id
for level 8 I want to search level 7 searched id 
for level 9 I want to search level 8 searched id
for level 10 I want to search level 9 searched id
```

**show like this**

```
Level  |   Connect Count      
-------+----------------
  1    |      2
  2    |      2
  3    |      2
  4    |      1
  5    |      1
  6    |      1
  7    |      0
  8    |      0
  9    |      0
 10    |      0
```

**My current php code**

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","");
$i = 1;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="select count('$id') from user where connect = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql="select * from user where connect = '$id'";
$resultt=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$roww=mysqli_fetch_array($resultt);
// display records in a table
echo '<div style="overflow-x:auto;">';
echo "<table>";
// set table headers
echo "<tr><th>Level</th><th>User Count</th></tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>$i</th><th>" .$row[0].  "</th><th></th>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
echo "</table>";
echo '</div>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of the term 'level' in this context

Comment: Seems like a sort of MLM/downline/referal system.

Comment: yes @PatrickQ like MLM Down line can you please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a self join in your query:

```
select    a.id, 
          count(b.id) connect_count 
from      user a
left join user b on a.id = b.connect
group by  a.id
```